# cache control on subdomain in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, caching, tomcat7

I can handle cache on core domain say (www.domain.com) using below filter

```
public class cacheControl implements Filter{

    FilterConfig filterConfig;

    public cacheControl() {
        filterConfig = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         String sCache = filterConfig.getInitParameter("cache");
        if (sCache != null) {
            Date _currentDate = new Date();
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Cache-Control", sCache);
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Expires", new Date(_currentDate.getYear(), _currentDate.getMonth(), _currentDate.getDate() + 10).toString());
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge, chrome=1");
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        filterConfig = null;
    }
}
```

But i put static content like javascripts, css, images on (static.domain.com) and I want to set expiry header for content coming from that static domain. I googled but there is no perfect solution. Please help me to set expiry header for static domain....

Comment: Add the filter into your root `web.xml` and check the URL of the incoming request.

Comment: I added filter in web.xml

Comment: You could add some parameters to the `Filter` - these work as standard java beans - to make it customisable. But all you need to do if you want to hardcode it is check the URL and branch on its value.